# Quantmod::getSymbols() recently causes an HTTP error 404

Tags: r, quantmod

The function `quantmod::getSymbols()` worked in the past but recently causes an error. However, the data is still available on the Yahoo Finance website, and the code works with some other tickers, e.g. GOOGL, but not with CELG.

```
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c( "GOOGL",  "CELG")
prices <- lapply(tickers, getSymbols, auto.assign=FALSE, from="2011-01-01")
```

The error I get is:

```
Warning: CELG download failed; trying again.
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "CELG", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “CELG”.
CELG download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 404.
```

Comment: Those ticker symbols aren't available. A quick check on Yahoo Finance shows CELG isn't found there. A quick test call with `tickers <- c( "GOOG",  "MSFT")` shows `quantmod::getSymbols()` to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

On November 20th 2019, Bristol Meyers Squibb completed its acquisition of [Celgene](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/bristol-myers-squibb-completes-74-billion-acquisition-of-celgene-2019-11-20). Therefore, Celgene is no longer publicly traded as an independent company and its stock ticker isn't accessible on Yahoo Finance through the `quantmod` R package.